# SQL Query slows down when more IDs are added

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Hello so I am facing an issue with my SQL query. I need to get the average location for each ID on the maximal day. While the query below gives me the correct result it seems that the run time grows exponential depending on the number of IDS. So while it is almost real time for 1 or 2 IDS it takes a few minutes for 3 and very long for 5. So running 5 queries for 5 IDs is a lot faster than running a single one containing all 5.
(I have a lot of IDs for which I need to check this, also the database is quite big).

How does this happen and how do I avoid it?

My guess would be that the problem comes from having the same ID list selected twice but I am not sure how to fix it/ if this really is the problem. I toke a look at all the similar issues on stack overflow but I did not find any which was answering my problem.

```
SELECT t.ID, MAX(date) AS MAX(date), AVG(Latitude) AS lat, AVG(Longitude) AS long
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, max(date) AS maxdate
    FROM table1 t2
    WHERE ID IN ('1', '2', '3')
    GROUP BY ID
) tm ON t.ID = tm.ID AND t.date = tm.maxdate
WHERE t.ID IN ('1', '2', '3')
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Does your table `table1` actually have any indexes on it? If so, what are they? Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? Also, `WHERE ID IN (‘1’, '2', '3')` will generate an error; T-SQL won't treat "smart" quotes (`‘’`) as single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one row per `id, date` pair?

Comment: @Larnu  Hello, I changed the Id and there by got the wrong quotes. I have fixed it now above.
I am trying to get a list where I get the location of which each ID had on its most current day. 
My clustered index is a Columnstore on the table. I have non clustered index on the date and on the ID.
Sadly I am not allowed to post the execution plan for data protection reasons.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes there are usually around a hundred. I have an other column with the concrete Time which is realivant here.

Comment: *"Sadly I am not allowed to post the execution plan for data protection reasons."* An execution plan isn't going to break any data protection rules; especially if you anonymise any information that *might* do so.

Comment: On a side note: I hope in your real table this column is not called `ID`. A column called `ID` should uniquely identify a row as its name promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give window functions a try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
    FROM t
    WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3')
)
SELECT id, max(date), min(...)
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Wow this works really well (although I still needed the Group by). Is there a reason why this is so much faster?

Comment: It uses window functions so self-join is not used (`rank` function numbers the rows based on the specified order by; the row with max date is numbered 1). An index on `id, date` would still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `exists` operator in `where` clause as follows:

```
Select ID, MAX(date) as [date], AVG(Latitude) as lat, AVG(Longitude) as long
From table1 As t
Where ID In ('1', '2', '3')
      And Exists (Select * From table1 Where ID=t.ID Group by ID Having Max(date)=t.date)
Group by ID
```

On my sample table with 5 million rows, it's a bit faster than using the window function, especially with suitable indexes.